# a php function to check a 'deep' array value

Tags: php, array

I've just coded a little function to check and get a deep array value. Basically, I need to return the value or null if it's not set or does not exists, or in general not useful for databases records. I need to check things like `$myarray[key1][key2][key3]` etc..

```
function get_array_deep_value(array $array, array $fields){
  $value = $array;

  foreach($fields as $field){
    $v = $value[$field] ?? null;
    if(empty($v) && $v != 0){  // note: using != operator because it will convert '0' to 0 (while !== does not)
      $value = null; 
      break;
    } 
    $value = $v;
  }

  return $value;
}
```

Any possible improvements? :)

Comment: What if the deep value that you want is a zero, but your script returns null?  If you are going to call `empty()` that should happen before null coalescing.

Comment: Your `break` seems like it is part of a protective measure.  Would you prefer instead to `throw` an exception because the path to the desired element suffered a breakage? How do you differentiate between a truly found `null` and a fallback `null`?

Comment: @mickmackusa the break is there because if the value is not the one expected or is undefined/null/empty string, I want a null value. If $v == 0, it will return 0, not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend avoiding declaring single-use variables.  I also recommend throwing an exception when a broken path is passed into your function.  Better variable naming will help others to instantly understand your code.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vvFp5))

```
function get_array_deep_value(array $array, array $levelKeys) {
    foreach ($levelKeys as $index => $key) {
        if (!key_exists($key, $array)) {
            throw new Exception("key $key not found at level index $index");
        }
        $array = $array[$key];
    }
    return $array;
}

$myArray = [
    'one' => [
        'two' => [
            'three' => [
                4
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$pathArrays = [
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['one', 'two'],
    ['one'],
    ['two']
];

foreach ($pathArrays as $pathArray) {
    try {
        var_export(get_array_deep_value($myArray, $pathArray));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Comment: Hey, key_esists... Wow... Elegant... :) Thank you! But will the exception also break the loop?

Comment: No, it is `caught`.  Add another valid path to test this.

Comment: ' Add another valid path to test this': what do you mean?

Anyway, I need always null when the value is not found/valid, since that value will be written on a database field.

Comment: ' Add another valid path to test this' > ok this one I understood. Still, I'll need a null value not an exception, but the main idea of your script is great. I'll just edit it a little to acomodate my needs. Thank you.

Comment: Notice what happens to an empty array when it is the final value with your snippet. https://3v4l.org/idXTm  The `empty() && loose comparison` converts the empty array to `null` but it shouldn't.

Comment: You can assign the fallback variable in the `catch` body https://3v4l.org/rvhX9 or just return `null` without throwing an exception, but it will be a more professional approach to differentiate truly extracted values from fallback values.

Comment: 'empty() && loose comparison converts the empty array to null' > that's what I want since the value must be saved on a database field, and when there's an empty array, I need it to be saved as null.

Comment: Fair enough, then that logical requirement should be expressed in your question and in your project's code.